# Intelij: how to track the time spent waiting for builds?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, build

Is there a built-in way or a plugin for *IntelliJ* that tracks waiting for *Java* builds to finish?

Comment: Not that I know of. Your CI/CD workflow should track build times. You are using CI/CD?

Comment: Yea using CI/CD. Would like this to make it easier to justify a faster laptop at work.

Comment: Do like we did in the old days. Why are you goofing off in the break room? Waiting for the automated test suite to finish.